# Is there an easy way to create a partitioned table from a managed table in Hive?

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, partition

I have a managed table in hive that I would like to partitioned based one of its columns.
is there an easy way to create a partitioned table from this managed table?

managed table a (s,d,f,g,h,j,k, key)

create table b as table a partitioned by key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by Dynamic partitioning:

Here is an example:
I have some log data, that has fields

id, tdate, info
I have created a dynamic partitioned table

```
CREATE TABLE log_partitioned(id STRING,  info STRING)
PARTITIONED BY ( tdate STRING)
```

and then Load the data

```
FROM logs lg
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE log_partitioned PARTITION(tdate)
SELECT lg.id, lg.info, lg.tdate
DISTRIBUTE BY tdate;
```

It will successfully loading the data by dynamic partitioning from managed table.

I found this tutorial very useful. Please refer to this "http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-speed-up-your-hive-queries-in.html"